# From base64-encoded public key in DER format to COSE key, in Python

Tags: python, cryptography, asn.1, der, cbor

I have a base64-encoded public key in DER format.
In Python, how can I convert it into a COSE key?

Here is my failed attempt:

```
from base64 import b64decode
from cose.keys import CoseKey

pubkeyder = "...=="
decCborData.key = CoseKey.decode(b64decode(pubkeyder))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The posted key is an EC key for curve P-256 in X.509 format.

With an ASN.1 parser (e.g. https://lapo.it/asn1js/) the x and y coordinates can be determined:

```
x: 0x1AF1EA7FB498B65BDEBCEC80FE7A3E8B5FD67264B46CE60FD5B80FFA92538D39
y: 0x013A9422F9FEC87BAE35E56165F5AA2ACCC98A449984E94AF81FE6FD55B6BB14
```

Then the COSE key can be generated simply as follows:

```py
from cose.keys import EC2Key

pub_x = bytes.fromhex('1AF1EA7FB498B65BDEBCEC80FE7A3E8B5FD67264B46CE60FD5B80FFA92538D39')
pub_y = bytes.fromhex('013A9422F9FEC87BAE35E56165F5AA2ACCC98A449984E94AF81FE6FD55B6BB14')
cose_pub_key = EC2Key(crv='P_256', x=pub_x, y=pub_y)
```

For details, s. the [cose library](https://pycose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cose/keys/ec2.html#cose.keys.ec2.EC2Key) documentation and RFC8152, CBOR Object Signing and Encryption (COSE), especially [chapter 13](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8152#section-13).

---

The determination of the x and y coordinates can also be done programmatically, e.g. with [PyCryptodome](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```py
from Crypto.PublicKey import ECC
import base64

der = base64.b64decode('MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEGvHqf7SYtlvevOyA/no+i1/WcmS0bOYP1bgP+pJTjTkBOpQi+f7Ie6415WFl9aoqzMmKRJmE6Ur4H+b9Vba7FA==')
key = ECC.import_key(der)
pub_x = key.pointQ.x.to_bytes()
pub_y = key.pointQ.y.to_bytes()
```